# Read arbitrary lines from file

Tags: filesystem-access

Is there an easy way to read arbitrary lines from a file? For example "read line number 12" or "read backwards from last line to first line" or "read lines 1,3,5...".

Comment: You can use the packages listings or fancyvrb

Comment: @Macro: Yes, but AFAIK unfortunately they can't do something like "read backwards from last line to first line" (Not a good example anyway) or remove the last *n* lines, because both don't know the number of total lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't read arbitrary lines, but you can't do that in most other programming languages either. You have to read line after line from the beginning.
Apart from the `\read` primitive, there is also the `\readline` primitive which reads a line verbatim. You can use that to save all lines in macros and use these afterward:

```
\newread\myread
\newcount\linecnt
\openin\myread=file.dat
\@whilesw\unless\ifeof\myread\fi{%
  \advance\linecnt by \@ne
  \readline\myread t\expandafter o\csname line-\number\linecnt\endcsname
}
```

Comment: I do not understand how can I use macros which is contain the lines? like \line-12 ?

Comment: @sergiokapone You have to use it like `\csname line-12\endcsname`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\readline\myread to \expandafter\csname line-\number\linecnt\endcsname` ?

Answer (score 9):

TeX is able to read lines from a file as long as they have balanced braces. This is accomplished through `\openin` and `\read`.

```
\newread\myread
\openin\myread=file.dat
\read\myread to \command
```

Now `\command` will expand to the contents of the first line in `file.dat` and a subsequent `\read\myread to \command` will do the same with the following line. The end of the file can be tested with `\ifeof\myread`, but one should always keep in mind that TeX appends an empty line to each file. The symbolic name `\myread` can be reused after having closed the file with `\closein\myread`.

It must be mentioned the possibility of calling, via "shell-escape", external utilities that may be faster and more flexible.

---

## Update

After nine years it's time to do an update. Here's a set of macros for outputting selected lines from a file with some tokens between each line. An application is given for a table.

The first argument is the file name, the second one is a comma separated list of ranges. Start and end of the range are separated by `/`; if an index is negative, it means starting from the end. Take into account that the range is always set “going up”. So if you specify `3/1` you get lines from 1 to 3 in this order.

However, if `\readfromfile*` is called, the lines are reversed. So `\readfromfile*{1/3}` will print the lines from 3 to 1 in this order. The reversal is done at the last moment, so be sure to specify the ranges also in reverse order.

A trailing optional argument specifies what to insert between lines, default nothing.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tab}
line 1 & line 1
line 2 & line 2
line 3 & line 3
line 4 & line 4
line 5 & line 5
line 6 & line 6
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\readfromfile}{s m m +O{}}
 {% #1 = * if reversing
  % #2 = file name, #3 = list of lines, #4 = what to use between items
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   { \bool_set_true:N \l__malmedal_rff_reverse_bool }
   { \bool_set_false:N \l__malmedal_rff_reverse_bool }
  \malmedal_rff_main:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\bool_new:N \l__malmedal_rff_reverse_bool
\ior_new:N \g__malmedal_rff_file_ior
\seq_new:N \l__malmedal_rff_items_seq
\seq_new:N \l__malmedal_rff_items_out_seq
\clist_new:N \l__malmedal_rff_lines_clist

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n { e } { p,T,F,TF }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \malmedal_rff_main:nnn
 {
  % clear the variables
  \seq_clear:N \l__malmedal_rff_items_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l__malmedal_rff_items_out_seq
  \clist_clear:N \l__malmedal_rff_lines_clist
  % read the file line by line and stores them in a sequence
  \ior_open:Nn \g__malmedal_rff_file_ior { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g__malmedal_rff_file_ior
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__malmedal_rff_items_seq { \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g__malmedal_rff_file_ior
  % output the items we want
  \__malmedal_rff_output:nn { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__malmedal_rff_output:nn
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__malmedal_rff_additems:n
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__malmedal_rff_lines_clist
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__malmedal_rff_items_out_seq { \seq_item:Nn \l__malmedal_rff_items_seq { ##1 } }
   }
  \bool_if:NT \l__malmedal_rff_reverse_bool
   {
    \seq_reverse:N \l__malmedal_rff_items_out_seq
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__malmedal_rff_items_out_seq { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__malmedal_rff_additems:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { / } { #1 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq = 1 }
   {
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l__malmedal_rff_lines_clist { #1 }
   }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnn
     {
      \tl_if_empty:eTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
       { 1 }
       {
        \int_compare:nTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } < 0 }
         {
          \seq_count:N \l__malmedal_rff_items_seq + (\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 }) + 1
         }
         { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
       }
     }
     {
      \tl_if_empty:eTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }
       { \seq_count:N \l__malmedal_rff_items_seq } % all the way up
       {
        \int_compare:nTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } < 0 }
         {
          \seq_count:N \l__malmedal_rff_items_seq + (\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 }) + 1
         }
         { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }
       }
     }
     { \clist_put_right:Nn \l__malmedal_rff_lines_clist { ##1 } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

All lines\par
\readfromfile{\jobname.dat}{/}[\par]

All lines\par
\readfromfile{\jobname.dat}{1/}[\par]

All lines\par
\readfromfile{\jobname.dat}{1/-1}[\par]

\bigskip
Lines 1 and 4 to end\par
\readfromfile{\jobname.dat}{1,4/}[\par]

\bigskip
Lines from 1 to penultimate\par
\readfromfile{\jobname.dat}{1/-2}[\par]

\bigskip
Lines from antepenultimate to last\par
\readfromfile{\jobname.dat}{-3/-1}[\par]

\newpage

Reverse\par
\readfromfile*{\jobname.dat}{/}[\par]

\bigskip
Last and penultimate lines in reverse\par
\readfromfile*{\jobname.dat}{1/2}[\par]

\bigskip
Table with select lines\par
\begin{tabular}{ll}
A & B \\
\hline
\readfromfile{\jobname.tab}{2/4}[\\]
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
Table with all lines in reverse\par
\begin{tabular}{ll}
A & B \\
\hline
\readfromfile*{\jobname.tab}{/}[\\]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

What you are asking about here is "random access" to the lines of text file, which is not supported by any filesystem that I know of. Most programming languages have a `seek` function that can "jump" forward and backwards in a file by a given number of **bytes**. This works well in binary files or text files where every line is the same length since the byte offset of "jump to position x" can be calculated.

Unfortunately, most text files have a varying number of bytes per line so it is impossible to predict the offset at which a given line begins without reading the contents of the file. To get around this problem, you need to "index" the file in some way such that lines can be located in an arbitrary order.  Two methods that I am aware of are:

- Read the contents of the file, split it into lines and store the results in an array. The array index then provides random access to the file contents. This works well for small files.
- For large files, you have to worry about running out of time or memory. A common trick to conserve memory is to scan the file and store the byte offset of each line in an array rather that the contents of the line its self. These offsets can then be fed to `seek` in order to locate a line in the file. Perl's [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Tie-File-0.96/lib/Tie/File.pm) module uses this method along with some other tricks to represent large files as arrays.

---

Suppose we have the following input file:

```
foo
bar
baz
bim
```

With TeX you have two problems:

1. You can only read the file one line at a time---no fancy tricks such as a `seek` method that lets you jump over content.
2. Without the help of packages, no nice object that can be used as an array with operations like indexed lookup or maximum length.

#### Solution: Use LuaTeX

This is the easiest way to go since Lua tables make great array objects:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\def\readfile#1#2{%
  % Read the contents of a file #1 to an array and store the array name in #2
  \directlua{%
    local input = io.open('#1', 'r')
    #2 = {}
    for line in input:lines() do
      table.insert(#2, line)
    end
    input:close()
  }%
}

\begin{document}   
% Read the contents of io.in to foo
\readfile{io.in}{foo}

% Loop over foo any way you want. The Lua shortcut for table.getn(foo) is #foo,
% but the # character is also special to TeX which causes some confusion.
\directlua{%
  texio.write_nl("Normal:")%
  for i = 1, table.getn(foo) do texio.write_nl(foo[i]) end}

\directlua{%
  texio.write_nl("Reversed:")%
  for i = table.getn(foo), 1, -1 do texio.write_nl(foo[i]) end}

\directlua{%
  texio.write_nl("Odd entries only:")%
  for i = 1, table.getn(foo), 2 do texio.write_nl(foo[i]) end}

\end{document}
```

The `lualatex` log output is:

```
Normal:
foo
bar
baz
bim
Reversed:
bim
baz
bar
foo
Odd entries only:
foo
baz
```

Lua `FILE` objects such as `input` also have a `seek` method that can be used to pull off advanced tricks.

Answer (score 2):

I was also interested in this problem and I found a solution using the package `readarray`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file.dat}
1 row
2 row
3 row
4 row
5 row
6 row
7 row
8 row
9 row
10 row
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\newcounter{rand}
\newcounter{someline}

%\ReadLine{<file name>} read one random line from file <file name>
\def\RandLine#1{
\readrecordarray{#1}\data
\setcounter{rand}{\pdfuniformdeviate\dataROWS{}}
\ifnum\therand=0\stepcounter{rand}\fi
\data[\arabic{rand}]
}

%\ReadLine{<file name>}{<line number>} read one line with number <line number> from file <file name>
\def\ReadLine#1#2{
\readrecordarray{#1}\data
\setcounter{someline}{#2}
\data[\arabic{someline}]
}

%\ReadLine{<file name>}{<first line>}{<last line>} read lines from file <file name> from <first line> to <last line>
\def\ReadLines#1#2#3{
\readrecordarray{#1}\data
\setcounter{someline}{#2}
\newcount\i\i=#3
\advance\i by 1
\loop\ifnum\value{someline} < \i
\data[\arabic{someline}]\par
\stepcounter{someline}
\repeat
}


\begin{document}

\RandLine{file.dat}

\ReadLine{file.dat}{2}

=============================

\ReadLines{file.dat}{3}{6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. But did not work for my use case. I have 2 latex files `A.tex` and `B.tex`. A.tex produces a number, e.g., `N=7`. I can export it to a text file. I want to export N from A to B and use in `B.tex`. To prevent errors if I do manually, I want to do this programmatically. Any thoughts?