# Bold one line inside of lstlisting when \lstinputlisting is used

Tags: listings

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299401/bold-just-one-line-inside-of-lstlisting) shows how one line inside of `lstlisting` can be set
in bold face. However, in this solution, you need to put the
material in a `lstlisting` environment.

But what if I need to input the line using `\lstinputlisting`? What
should I do in this case?

Editing the input file is not an option. This file is machine generated
and is likely to change from time-to-time. But the line number of the line to 
be bolded does not change.

Though we don't need an MWE, I am providing one so that you can provide a solution with minimum hassle.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
First
Second
Third line to be bolded.
Fourth
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listings` has a lot of hooks you can (ab)use, here for example  `OutputBox`, which is called at the beginning of each line (after possibly typesetting a line number).

Additions to hooks are global, so if you want to limit the scope, use a macro and redefine it as required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{OutputBox}{\lst@boldline}
\let\lst@boldline\relax
\newcommand\lstboldline[1][3]{% optional argument to choose the line number?
    \def\lst@boldline{\ifnum\lst@lineno=#1 \bfseries\fi}}
\newcommand\lstnoboldline{\let\lst@boldline\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lstboldline
\lstinputlisting{\jobname.txt}

\lstnoboldline
\lstinputlisting{\jobname.txt}

\lstboldline[2]
\lstinputlisting{\jobname.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Looks like the hook becomes global even when set inside a scope. How do I unset this?

Comment: @Masroor See edit...

Comment: Is there any way to extend this to support multiple bold lines?  i.e. `\lstboldline[2,4]` or similar?

Answer (score 2):

**My approach:**

- You can read the file line for line using this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17671/123129) to [Read arbitrary lines from file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17664/read-arbitrary-lines-from-file/17671#17671)
- use a forloop and a if condition to adapt the specified line to [make it bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299401/bold-just-one-line-inside-of-lstlisting)
- write each line using `\immediate\write\tempfile{...}`
- use `\lstinputlisting[escapeinside={(*}{*)}]{\jobname.tmp}` to show the adapted code

For this I made the command `boldlineCode{<number of lines>}{<bold line>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
First
Second
Third line to be bolded.
Fourth
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{ct}

% boldlineCode
% #1 = number of lines
% #2 = bold line
\newcommand{\boldlineCode}[2]{
    \newwrite\tempfile
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.tmp
    \newread\myread
    \openin\myread=\jobname.txt
    % read lines, insert bold command in line #2 and write
    \forloop{ct}{1}{\numexpr\value{ct}-1 < #1}%
    {%
        \read\myread to \command
        \ifthenelse{\value{ct}=#2}{
            \immediate\write\tempfile{(*\unexpanded{\bfseries} \command*)}
        }{
            \immediate\write\tempfile{\command}
        }
    }
    \immediate\closeout\tempfile
    \lstinputlisting[escapeinside={(*}{*)}]{\jobname.tmp}
}

\begin{document}

\boldlineCode{4}{3}

\boldlineCode{4}{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]