# How can I read the whole file content verbatim into a (expl3) string variable?

Tags: expl3, external-files

### Problem Description

As in the title.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

% first write some file content for demo...
\begin{filecontents*}{test test.txt}
line 1  !?#\xyz
line 2
\end{filecontents*}

% what to do here? I want to read the whole content of the file into variable \result

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_show:N \result  % → the whole content of the file.
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found several very-similar questions (see links below), but none that is exactly identical to this one.

Comment: Side note, if the file is huge, you may want to refrain from using this method.

Comment: TeX doesn't work with strings, so "string variable" in nonsense from TeX point of view. There are only token lists in TeX.

Comment: @wipet The question title contains “(expl3) string variable”. String variables are perfectly well defined in `expl3`. The question didn't mention that computational complexity was a concern, but its “string variable” part, at least, is clear. In case it is not for you, see “The l3str package: Strings” in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf).

Comment: @frougon Because expl3 is based on TeX and TeX doesn't work with strings, something like "string variable" is only mystification and denial of TeX principles. This can bring only misunderstanding. Moreover `\string` primitive is something different, so misunderstanding is very probable.

Comment: @wipet There is no catcode ambiguity in an `expl3` string, and only character tokens. I bet you didn't read the first 8 lines of the chapter I pointed you to. Which means, I am wasting my time.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `\file_get:nnN`. There are other options as well.

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{test test.txt}
line 1  !?#\xyz
line 2
\end{filecontents*}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\file_get:nnN {test~test.txt} {
    % alternatively (although the effects the different on LuaTeX)
    %   \int_step_inline:nnn {0} {255} {\char_set_catcode_other:n{#1}}
    \cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab
    \endlinechar=10~
    % ↑ this must be done after the cctab line
    %   because cctab changes the value of endlinechar as well
} \result
\str_set:NV \result \result

\str_show:N \result  % → the whole content of the file.
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

This saves the whole content of the file into variable `\result`, each "new line character" in the file will be represented with a character 10.

#### Explanation

```
\file_get:nnN {test~test.txt} {
```

Use the command, as explained. Note that since this is expl3 environment the space need to be written as `~`.

```
    \cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab
```

Set the catcode. On XeTeX it's impractical to set for all the characters in 0..1114111,
so there exists corner cases
where one of the characters in the file
has catcode 1/2 and make the content unbalanced thus cause an error.

Note that this command, in addition to setting the **catcode table** as its name suggests, it also sets the **endlinechar** (in this catcode table endlinechar = -1),
as such we want char with charcode 10 to separate the lines we need to explicitly set it below.

```
    \endlinechar=10~
```

Set endlinechar to 10, so each new line character in the file will be represented with a character 10 <sub>to be precise, a token with char code 10 and catcode 12</sub> in the resulting string.

This is expl3 environment it's good practice to specify the space explicitly to terminate the number (or use `\scan_stop:` / `\relax` but I don't like that name it's longer. There's also `\int_set:Nn \endlinechar {10}` but that... relies on implementation details...?)

```
} \result
\str_set:NV \result \result
```

Detokenize the result. This step is important, because in order to get the result as a string,
tokens with charcode 32 (space) should have catcode 10 (space),
while it would have catcode 12 (other) as above.

#### Limitations

- First (for XeTeX/LuaTeX engine only), if there happens to be some character with char code ≥ 256 and some unusual catcode (e.g. catcode 1 -- open brace) it might break. Most of the time the detokenization can handle it however.
- If the file to be read is a TeX file, synctex data on that file might be "lost". (the details is complex.)
- Trailing spaces on each line are stripped (and maybe trailing tabs as well).

#### Related questions

- related code using `\readline`: [File copy without expansion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/file-copy-without-expansion?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Read arbitrary lines from file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17664/read-arbitrary-lines-from-file)
- read file in normal catcode regime/read using Lua: [Read a file and store its contents in a variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377118/read-a-file-and-store-its-contents-in-a-variable)
- pdffiledump solution: [Read file contents to variable and iterate over each character in file (hexdump)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505849/read-file-contents-to-variable-and-iterate-over-each-character-in-file-hexdump?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- "structured"/database-style files: [File input and output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2375/file-input-and-output)

Comment: Side note, the str_show might print something that doesn't make sense depends on your operating system, because character 10 is a CR or LF, something like that.

Comment: 1) In the paragraph starting with “Detokenize the result”, there is a mix between char code and catcode (swap needed). 2) `\str_show:n` should be `\str_show:N`. 3) I get “Undefined control sequence” for `\pretty:V`. I can fix these if you want...

Comment: @frougon Ah, that \pretty thing is an internal debugging macro for me, I keep forget to deleting them. Otherwise good points.

Comment: Would be nice to make a package out of this code

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use `\ior_str_map_variable:NNn`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
line 1  !?#\xyz
line 2
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g__my_ior
\str_new:N \l__my_str

\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_verb_read_into:Nn #1#2
  {
    \str_clear_new:N #1   % define #1 if necessary, then clear it

    \ior_open:Nn \g__my_ior {#2}
    \ior_str_map_variable:NNn \g__my_ior \l__my_str
      {
        % Precaution in case the LINE FEED char ^^J might be active
        \str_put_right:Nx #1 { \l__my_str \char_generate:nn { 10 } { 12 } }
      }
    \ior_close:N \g__my_ior
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \verbReadInto { m m }
  {
    \my_verb_read_into:Nn #1 {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\verbReadInto{\result}{test.txt}
\show\result

\end{document}
```

which shows:

```
\result=macro:
->line 1  !?#\xyz
line 2
.
```

All lines, including the last one, are terminated by a LINE FEED character (10) with catcode 12.

Of course, one could use `\g_tmpa_ior` and `\l_tmpa_str` in `\my_verb_read_into:Nn` (and spare the declarations of `\g__my_ior` and  `\l__my_str`), but be careful not to shoot yourself in the foot when the code grows with new functions that use the same scratch variables.

Actually, if it were not for space reasons in this tight space for the code block, I'd have included most of the function name in the names of these two variables, for the same reason.

Comment: Although note that this method takes time quadratic in the number of lines in the file. There's also \tl_build_put* functions (they're still quadratic) and e.g. \tokapp primitives etc.

Comment: Because of the repeated `\str_put_right:Nx`? I would hope it is cheap enough, but otherwise you could append each line separately to a `seq` variable (I hope this is linear but haven't checked).

Comment: At the moment (my TeXlive version at least) seq is represented as `\s__seq\__seq_item:n{1}\__seq_item:n{2}\__seq_item:n{3}` so each change need to change the whole thing, quadratic as well.

Comment: Yes, I have now looked at the code of `\seq_put_right:Nn` and I believe `\str_put_right:Nn` has the same complexity (time and memory) as `\seq_put_right:Nn`. That said, whether it is quadratic depends on the complexity of expanding a macro in function of, say, the number of tokens inside the macro (judging from the code of `\tl_put_right:Nn`). I don't know how it is done in TeX impementations, just wondering if you are too pessimistic.

Comment: Just a short note: `l3candidates` has `\tl_build_put_right:Nx` and friends that might be relevant here (“`\tl_build_begin:N` Clears the ⟨tl var⟩ and sets it up to support other `\tl_build_...` functions, which allow accumulating large numbers of tokens piece by piece much more efficiently than standard `l3tl` functions”).

Comment: Not that I *require* answers to have linear time complexity, just point out properties for (future readers) to be aware of when choosing a solution. ---------- I know that thing, last time I check I think it's a "still quadratic but smaller constant factor" I think? (from source3:  "there are between 0 and 4 \exp_end: to keep track of when <left> and <right> should be put into the <next tl>" so I guess it's 5 times faster)

Comment: Correction, it actually uses that to accumulate token into next level once per 5 changes of previous levels, so each piece of data is actually only moved only about log(n) times where n is the number of appends. Or so I think.

Comment: I looked at the code of  `\tl_build_begin:N`, `\tl_build_put_right:Nn`, `\tl_build_get:NN` and `\tl_build_end:N`. Regarding `\tl_build_put_right:Nn`, I am not comfortable giving a precise complexity class, but indeed, I'd say the data of each append is copied into a new node ceil(log5(n)) times except for “isolated cases”.